# Camel JSON array body

Tags: json

I have a JSON array in the route, tell me how can I call the rest service by passing the id array parameter there and call the rest as many times as there are "userID" elements in the array?

```
 {"data": [
    {
        "userID": 8053,
        "userDisplayName": "User 1",
        "eMail": "user1@mail.com",
        "year": 2019,
        "month": 5,
        "dayNum": 21,
        "startTimeAvg": 60328,
        "endTimeAvg": 60617,
        "durationSum": 289,
        "activeTimeSum": 289,
        "unproductivity": 289
    },
    {
        "userID": 9063,
        "userDisplayName": "User 2",
        "eMail": "user2@mail.com",
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 4,
        "dayNum": 15,
        "startTimeAvg": 60328,
        "endTimeAvg": 60617,
        "durationSum": 289,
        "activeTimeSum": 500,
        "unproductivity": 500
    },
    {
        "userID": 6548,
        "userDisplayName": "User 3",
        "eMail": "user3@mail.com",
        "year": 2020,
        "month": 5,
        "dayNum": 18,
        "startTimeAvg": 60328,
        "endTimeAvg": 60617,
        "durationSum": 289,
        "activeTimeSum": 300,
        "unproductivity": 300
    }
]}
```

Already done, there is a route that calls the rest service and writes the response parameters to the database. Now I need to call the second service using the userID from the body of the first call in the parameters. Tell me how can I do this?

```
 from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000").
            log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Cron job kicked off").
            setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET")).
            setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json")).
            setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("selectFields=userID,userDisplayName,year,month,dayNum,startTimeAvg,endTimeAvg,durationAvg,activeTimeSum,unproductivity")).
           to("http://172.27.79.78:8900/rest/SearchInform/1.0/api/v2/report_center/reports/user_activity").
            unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(JsonList.class)).
            log("MESSAGE BODY!!!!!  ${body.getData.size()} 
            Split: ${body.getData.size()}").
            loop(simple("${body.getData.size()}")).
           
    to("sql:insert into XX_DSS_SI.USER_ACTIVITY values " +
    "(:#${body.getData.get(${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}).getUserID}," +
    ":#${body.getData.get(${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}).getUserDisplayName}," +
    ":#${body.getData.get(${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}).geteMail}).getUnproductivity})" +
    "?dataSource=#exampleDatasource").
    
      end().
      to( "direct:endFirstRout");
```

Comment: you need to show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

try to set json property

```
[JsonProperty("userID")] 
public string Id {get;set;}
```

Comment: Сan you give an example of how I can use JsonProperty in my route, thanks.